# UWP: Get Artist / Title of URL Webradio Stream

Tags: uwp, stream, media-player, webradio, mediaplayerelement

Is it possible to extract Artist / Title with the MediaPlayerElement / MediPlayer / MediaItem Classes in UWP, if it's delivered in the Web Stream?
f.e. this URL https://swr-dasding-live.cast.addradio.de/swr/dasding/live/mp3/128/stream.mp3 delivers with the AIMP Radioplayer exactly the Artist / Title. But with my MediaPlayerElement I can't get this. I have already added events to the MediaItem. But they are only triggered the first time and give "0" back.

```
 using Windows.Media.Core;
 using Windows.Media.Playback;
////////// USINGS ABOVE ///
 MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
 MediaSource _mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(https://swr-dasding-live.cast.addradio.de/swr/dasding/live/mp3/128/stream.mp3"));
 MediaPlaybackItem mpItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(_mediaSource);
 mpItem.AudioTracksChanged += PlaybackItem_AudioTracksChanged;
 mpItem.TimedMetadataTracksChanged += PlaybackItem_TimedMetadataTracksChanged;
 mpItem.VideoTracksChanged += PlaybackItem_VideoTracksChanged;
 mp.Source = mpItem;
 mp.Play();
```

Hope someone can give me a hint how to get this working.
Thanks in advance
Christian

Comment: I tested the music from the linked URL, it seems that the information of the music file does not contain the `Artist` and `Title` information. You could use the following code to get `Artist` and `Title` information:             `var properties = mpItem.GetDisplayProperties(); var artist = properties.MusicProperties.Artist;  var title = properties.MusicProperties.Title;`

Comment: f.e. the AIMP player (https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9PCLLLH15SMT) can extract the artist and title of the current track. I don't know how this player gets the details :( But they must be included

Comment: You could try to download the web stream to local machine and read the information about Artist or Title for the music file.